# JSON Schema: How to require to have one of the property names or none of them and any different name?

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

There is `msgId1` that must have `a1` and `msgId2` that must have `a2`.

This should be valid:

```
{ "msgId1": { "a1": "b1" } }
```

This too:

```
{ "msgId2": { "a2": "b2" } }
```

And this:

```
{ "msgIdUnknownYet": { "a3": "b3" } }
```

That's invalid:

```
{
    "msgId1": { "a1": "b1" },
    "msgId2": { "a2": "b2" }
}
```

That should be invalid too:

```
{
    "msgId1": { "abc": "b1" },
    "msgId2": { "a2": "b2" }
}
```

If I use `oneOf`, then it doesn't allow the unknown messages. And it also allows to add wrong `msgId1` or `msgId2` if at least one of the right `msgId` is present. How to write a schema for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dependencies` for this.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "msgId1": { "required": ["a1"] },
    "msgId2": { "required": ["a2"] }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "msgId1": { "not": { "required": ["msgId2"] } }
  }
}
```

This effectively says that if "msgId1" is present, then "msgId2" can not be present.  This way, it still passes if neither "msgId1" or "msgId2" are present.

Comment: I've got like 20 of them. Then I do msgId1, but not msg2/msg3/msg4..., then msgId2, but not msg1/msg3/msg4?

Answer (score 0):

Works if there is a way to isolate them and limit the total number of properties. This tells: if there is a property with such name, then it must have that specific form, and the total number of properties is no more than 1.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "header": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": { "type": "integer" }
        },
        "required": ["id"]
    },
    "messageHeader": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "token": { "type": "string" }
        },
        "required": ["token"]
    },
    "msgId1": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": { "a1": { "type": "string" } },
      "required": ["a1"]
    },
    "msgId2": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": { "a2": { "type": "string" } },
      "required": ["a2"]
    }
  },

  "type": "object",
  "dependencies": {
    "msgId1": { "type": "object", "properties": { "msgId1": { "$ref": "#/definitions/msgId1" } } },
    "msgId2": { "type": "object", "properties": { "msgId2": { "$ref": "#/definitions/msgId2" } } }
  },
  "maxProperties": 1
}
```